# Building a blender platform for reuse with product render

Tags: rendering

I am setting up a Diamond Jewelry product render, I have gotten all the settings for the render, and generally happy with the quality of the image.

Currently I have a 200-300 products that will be rendered and obviously new products will keep getting added.

As of right now, I am loading each product's obj file in its own blender file, which means I will end up having 200-300 .blend files. If in the future I come across a little tweak to the settings/material that makes the render better/faster, is there any way to cascade this change to the 200-300 .blend files that have already been made.

I was thinking along the lines of a linked main/master .blend file, which would have the render scene/scenes created, and the product's .blend files would use these scene/scenes linked from the main/master file

I am not sure if the question is clear, but what I am aiming to do is have a "master" .blend file that will act as a platform, and the product blend files would link the scenes from this master file

Comment: Cycles is not able to [calculate accurate caustics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(optics)) so even someone provides a feasible solution the rendering won't come out as good as you might need it to be.

Comment: I am using Octane's render engine (with Blender), and as I have said I am happy with the quality of the renders